# Django seems to be caching?

Tags: python, django

I'm running Django 1.2.1 for my personal website with a blog. It's all fine and dandy, but I've found that all the browsers I've tried (Firefox, Chromium, Opera) are caching webpages, which of course is a problem for other users viewing my blog (being that it won't load new posts up unless they empty their cache or force refresh the page). I didn't have this problem when my site ran on PHP, so how would I go about fixing this seemingly Django-related problem?

I've only been working with Django for about a week or so, so I don't really know where abouts I should be looking to fix something like this. Thanks in advance!

The way I do each page (and each blog post) is as a Page/Post object respectively so I can use the admin interface without having to write my own. Although the issue is happening for both situations, I'll just give the Post class for now:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=User.objects.get(username='nathan'))
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default=Status.objects.get(text='Draft'))
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

    def link(self):
        return u'/blog/post/%s' % self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

And here's my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *                                                                       
from django.views.generic import list_detail

from feeds import PostFeed

from models import Post

blog_posts = { 
    'queryset': Post.objects.filter(status__text__exact='Published'),
}

urlpatterns = patterns('getoffmalawn.blog.views',
    (r'^$', list_detail.object_list, blog_posts),
    (r'^archive/(\d{4})$', 'archive'),
    (r'^rss/$', PostFeed()),
    (r'^search/$', 'search'),
    (r'^tag/(.+)/$', 'tag'),
    (r'^post/(.+)/$', 'post'),
)
```

If you guys would like to see the code from views.py, just ask and I'll throw that up too.

Edit:

Here's the views.

view.py for the blog App:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect                                                                              
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.db.models import Q

from models import Post, Category

def post(request, title):
    post = Post.objects.get(title=title)
    c = locals()
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('blog/post_detail.html', c)

def blog_detail(request, blog_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=blog_id)

    return list_detail.object_detail(request, queryset=Post.objects.all(), object_id=blog_id)

def archive(request, month, year):
    pass

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET['q']

        object_list = Post.objects.filter(Q(post__icontains=query) | Q(title__icontains=query), status__text__exact='Published')

        return render_to_response('blog/post_list_sparse.html', locals())

def tag(request, tag):
    object_list = Post.objects.filter(categories__text__exact=tag, status__text__exact='Published')
    return render_to_response('blog/post_list.html', locals())
```

Comment: That sounds weird... clean the cache to refresh the page? You always need to refresh the page if you want to see what new happened there. This is not the case if you using auto-resfresh in your site or you using AJAX to load the content and it load new item when it is created without refreshing the page. Maybe I misunderstood the question but...

Comment: Any reason why you are running Django 1.2.1 instead of Django 1.3?

Comment: I've run into a problem where I thought caching was the culprit, but the lazy evaluation of querysets caused my issue. Have you written a lot of custom code? Could you show it to us?

Comment: @Ken, I'm using Django 1.2.1 instead of 1.3 because that's what my host provides by default. I'm planning on updating to 1.3 myself when I get the time. @LaundroMat, I think you may be right. I was thinking this last night, I'll put the code up now.

Comment: Please add the views.py.  Also did you write any custom middleware if so, show that as well. Is it all pages or just a few, if a few which ones?

Comment: Nope, no custom middleware. I've added the views.py for the blog app as that's the one that's causing me the most trouble. Also, it's all pages.

Comment: I've narrowed this down a bit. After some investigating, it's only to do with pages using generic views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that it *really was* browser-based caching, as I was told by a member on the Django-users mailing list. The reason I didn't see this problem in PHP is that it was sending cache suppression headers.

The solution was to add the `@never_cache decorator` to the relevant views.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for caching in django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/cache/

Not ideal, but you can make all of the pages tell the browsers not to cache anything, to see if that helps.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers

Comment: Thanks for that Ken. I'll use this as a last resort if we can't manage to sort something out.